# Table with dynamic number of columns to show

Tags: c#, repeater

I have a data table with data like "insurance name, plantype, premium...." for each row.

So on my front end I have to show like below:

```
Insurance Name     HealthNet       Harvard         UniCare

Plan Type            HMO            PPO              HMO  

Premium              100            150             200
```

So sometimes I may have only two columns to show HealthNet and Harvard. Sometimes more than three. How to use repeater in this case to make it dynamic based on data table count?

Thanks

Comment: any particular reason for `repeater`? this can be easily achieved using `GridView` with `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`

Comment: Can you provide me any samples?

Answer (score 1):

Sample:

`aspx` markup as shown below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

In codebehind simply do this:

```
gv.DataSource = yourDataTable;   // doesn't matter how many columns are there, it will handle it automatically
gv.DataBind();
```

Comment: m sure u r rendering `html table` in your `repeater`....whereas `gridview` renders `html table` by default...so just mention your `datatable` to the `gridview` `datasource`

Comment: +1 for AutoGenerateColumn. But maybe you can add examples on how to specify the column names? By default (if using classes), we cannot add whitespace in column name.

Answer (score 0):

This will help how to pivot a data table:

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/05/10/pivot-data-in-gridview---a-generic-pivot-method-with.aspx

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to customize the table data inside 'td'. Like insert an image on certain conditions?