# Customize gridview with autogeneratedcolumns option 'true' and data bind from pivot data table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asked this question already here:[Table with dynamic number of columns to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621099/table-with-dynamic-number-of-columns-to-show/15621820#15621820)

But i have few more questions on this one.

1.I have a data table with data like insurance name, plantype, premium...." for each row

On my front end I need to show like:

```
Insurance Name     HealthNet       Harvard         UniCare

Plan Type            HMO            PPO              HMO  

Premium              100            150             200
```

For this I am using following method to pivot data table and assigning it to gridview)

```
private DataTable PivotTable(DataTable origTable){

        DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        //Add Columns to new Table
        for (int i = 0; i <= origTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(origTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, typeof(String)));
        }

        //Execute the Pivot Method
        for (int cols = 0; cols < origTable.Columns.Count; cols++)
        {
            dr = newTable.NewRow();
            for (int rows = 0; rows < origTable.Rows.Count; rows++)
            {
                if (rows < origTable.Columns.Count)
                {
                    dr[0] = origTable.Columns[cols].ColumnName; // Add the Column Name in the first Column
                    dr[rows + 1] = origTable.Rows[rows][cols];
                }
            }
            newTable.Rows.Add(dr); //add the DataRow to the new Table rows collection
        }
        return newTable;
}
```

And data binding as follows:

```
DataTable tempTable = PivotTable(actualDataTable);
myGridView.DataSource = tempTable;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Now my out put looks like:

```
Insurance Name     HealthNet       Harvard         UniCare

Plan Type            HMO            PPO              HMO  

Premium              100            150             200
```

But now my grid view showing all the values from the data source. I want to customize my grid view look So that I can insert image into table row next to each insurance name and hide some of the rows also.

Note: I am not restricted only to gridview. I am fine with any control but, data should be dynamic instead of hard coding.

Thanks

EDIT:

Can i loop through based on number of columns instead of following to display image next to each insurance name.

```
protected void myGridview_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<img src=../images/" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + ".png />";
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "<img src=../images/" + e.Row.Cells[2].Text + ".png />";

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event of GridView.

In RowDataBound event, you can manipulate each cell's data. For example, insert an image to a cell.

However, you cannot hide an entire row. If you do not want to display a row, you need to implement that logic inside PivotTable method.